# Own email domain hosting

Tags: ubuntu, email, hosts

Is is possible to host a own email domain for free. I mean like host it myself but without buying a domain.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You may use free DNS (sub) domain.

I may recommend it for "initial tests".
I do not recommend it as a long term solution for any **serious** email system.

Comment: What do you recommend for serious email system

Comment: Above "family server" level I recommend normal DNS domain.